# Expanding and collapsing in UL tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have the follwing HTML, where there is a collapse (**collapsebutton1**) and expand button (**expandbutton1**) which will collapse and expand the div ***networkDevicesCollapsePanel***, this is working as expected.

Now i need to bring the collapse and expand in each < UL >. There are three UL here, but there may be more later. How to achieve this?

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
<div class="panel" id="networkDevicesLinks">
 <div style="float:right;">                                       
                <div ng-show="ciAttributesCount>0" id="collapsebutton1" class="nodisp expandcollapse expand-collapse-new-link-button no-print"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>Collapse All</div>
                <div ng-show="ciAttributesCount>0" id="expandbutton1" class="disp expandcollapse expand-collapse-new-link-button no-print"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Expand All</div>
            </div>
 <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="networkDevicesCollapsePanel">
                    <ul ng-repeat="nav in ciRelationshipHierarchyBySection" style="background:none; padding:0 10px;margin:5px;" class="nav nav-list">
                        <li>
                            <a style="cursor:pointer; padding: 2px 12px;" ng-click="showNetworkDevices(nav.IdentificationSourceId)">{{nav.IdentifySourceName}}</a> <span style="padding: 2px 12px;">Source Id: {{nav.IdentificationSourceId}}</span><br />

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Button Click code below

```
 $("#expandbutton1").hide();

        $("#expandbutton1").click(function () {
            $('#networkDevicesLinks div.panel-collapse').addClass('in').css("height", "");
            $("#expandbutton1").hide();
            $("#collapsebutton1").show();

            $('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').each(function (index) {
                $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-plus-square-o").addClass("fa-minus-square-o");
            });
        });

        $("#collapsebutton1").click(function () {
            $('#networkDevicesLinks div.panel-collapse').removeClass('in');
            $("#expandbutton1").show();
            $("#collapsebutton1").hide();

            $('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').each(function (index) {
                $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-minus-square-o").addClass("fa-plus-square-o");
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: are you asking how to bind the new Expand/Collapse buttons to their respective <UL>?

Comment: yes... i need to add buttons for each UL repeats for expanding and collapsing

Comment: Updated the real code instead of rendered code

Comment: Hi @SmartestVEGA, you basically want to create an accordion within an accordion, right ? Have you looked at similar questions and their answers : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=accordion+within+accordion ?

Comment: those answers are pertaining to jquery and javascript, i need it in angularjs

Comment: Update the code again, simplified it, please have a close look

Comment: can you also include angular code with you current button click methods to toggle div visibility?

Comment: collapsebutton1 expandbutton1 are the buttons i use for toggle visibility of networkDevicesCollapsePanel which is working fine

Comment: Did you include bootstrap JS?

Comment: yes, its working,panel-collapse is comming from bootstrap.css

Comment: Updated the click button codes

Comment: Try use below code,my point is use data-toggle collapse bootstrap. Jquery click function no need drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may provide an idea,Try to use angular $index to toggle arrow and toggle client div.

And in angular we can assign each UL with dynamic classes which is hosted from expand and collapse button

```
                           <div class="col-xs-4">
                                    <div class="panel" id="networkDevicesLinks">
                                        <div style="float:right;" ng-repeat="nav in ciRelationshipHierarchyBySection track by $index">
                                            <div ng-show="ciAttributesCount" id="collapsebutton_{{$index}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#networkDevicesCollapsePanel_{{$index}}" class="nodisp expandcollapse expand-collapse-new-link-button no-print"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>Collapse All</div>
                                            <div ng-show="ciAttributesCount" id="expandbutton1_{{$index}}" class="disp expandcollapse expand-collapse-new-link-button no-print"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Expand All</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="" >
                                            <ul ng-repeat="nav in ciRelationshipHierarchyBySection track by $index" style="background:none; padding:0 10px;margin:5px;" class="nav nav-list panel-collapse collapse in" id="networkDevicesCollapsePanel_{{$index}}">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a style="cursor:pointer; padding: 2px 12px;" ng-click="showNetworkDevices(nav.IdentificationSourceId)">{{nav.IdentifySourceName}}</a> <span style="padding: 2px 12px;">Source Id: {{nav.IdentificationSourceId}}</span><br />
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Revised Code below:

I am able to put collapse button in each repeat, but when i click, it opening a popup , instead of collapsing and expanding. Please see where it is wrong

```
<div class="">

                        <ul ng-repeat="nav in ciRelationshipHierarchyBySection track by $index" style="background:none; padding:0 10px;margin:5px;" class="nav nav-list panel-collapse collapse in" id="networkDevicesCollapsePanel_{{$index}}">

                            <li>
 <div ng-show="ciAttributesCount" id="collapsebutton_{{$index}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#networkDevicesCollapsePanel_{{$index}}" class="nodisp expandcollapse  no-print"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>Collapse All</div>
                                <a style="cursor:pointer; padding: 2px 12px;" ng-click="showNetworkDevices(nav.IdentificationSourceId)">{{nav.IdentifySourceName}}</a>
                                <span style="padding: 2px 12px;">Source Id: {{nav.IdentificationSourceId}}</span>
                                <br />
                                <span style="padding: 2px 12px;">Data Source: {{nav.DataSource}}</span>
                                <br />
                                <span style="padding: 2px 12px;">Create New: {{nav.IsCreateNew}}</span>
                                <br />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: almost there some alignment issues ...let me check

Comment: three expand and collapse buttons are sitting together, but ideally it should somewhere near to left side of each repeat, thats the issue

Comment: In this case we need to move expand collapse buttons to ul tag above. and attached with each ul using with CSS

Comment: previus code was better, now when i click on expand, it is opening a popup, more only one collapse button working

Comment: can you revert the previous one please

Comment: Put your codes in jsfiddle. its related to CSS also.

Comment: I am able to put collapse button in each repeat, but when i click, it opening a popup , instead of collapsing and expanding. Please see where it is wrong

Comment: See refrence: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible&stacked=h

Comment: Expand and collapse button above the UL. its is working like sibling tags between collapse button tag and ul tag.

Comment: i just want one button for collapsing and expanding that why i kept one

Comment: that button i kept inside repeat, so that it will repeat for each iteration, i didnt put another repeat for button, only problem now is, when i click on the button,expand and collapse not working

Comment: that is why we are asking jsfiddle/codepen.io..it could help for us. If expand/collapse is not working., we need to find first whether any console error is coming or anything bootstrap library version conflicts..Its related to version and class name attributes

Comment: Ok,Do one thing. Repeat one common div tag, inside that first child put as collapse/expand buttons tag and second child as ul tag and click it

Comment: Now, when i removed "expand-collapse-new-link-button" that click issue is gone, now i am able to collapse, but the only issue now is unable to expand :D